# System Error using From Clause with OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Using `adapter` it works fine but when I use `adapter2` I get an error.

Note: The code is for `form1`. I am using two groupboxes and two datagridviews.

```
   `private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataSet set = new DataSet();

    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\DatabesSystem.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
        adapter1();
        adapter2();
    }

    private void adapter1()
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select CID, Firstname, Middlename, Lastname, Address, Contact_Number, Email from Clients", connection);
            adapter.Fill(set, "Clients");
            table = set.Tables["Clients"];
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void adapter2()
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter2 = new OleDbDataAdapter("select Transaction_Number, Client_Name, Unit_Name, Full_Price, Down_Payment, Monthly_Payment, Remaning_Balance from Transaction", connection);
            adapter2.Fill(set, "Transaction");
            table = set.Tables["Transaction"];
            dataGridView2.DataSource = table;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }`
```

Comment: What error, please post the exact exception text?

Comment: Error : system error in FROM clause

Comment: You have two select statements. Which one is throwing error? Does your table has all the columns spesificied?

Comment: @Sefa The description said: The second one, select from transaction... So im guessing the name is not right.

Comment: @KielDred just before the second FROM it sais: "Remaning_Balance " shouldnt that be: "Remaining_Balance"?

Comment: thanks for your efforts problem has been solved!
sharing small things is a great value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Transaction` is a reserved key word in SQL. Try to write the table name in brackets:

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter2 = new OleDbDataAdapter("select Transaction_Number, Client_Name, Unit_Name, Full_Price, Down_Payment, Monthly_Payment, Remaning_Balance from [Transaction]", connection);
```

Or rename your table name in another one.